# How to prevent navigation to a component when a specific part of state is missing?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Firstly please excuse the poorly worded question.

I have a SPA which has a page with this route:

`/students`

The container for this page is `StudentsView.js`, inside of which I do this to get the list of students:

```
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.actions.loadStudents()
  }
```

This is a list of students, clicking on one will take you do the details page of the student based on the students ID:

`/student/5`

The component for this page is `StudentDetailView.js`

Now to avoid unnecessary API calls to improve performance during initial application load, I have not dispatched a call to the `loadStudents()` action which sets the students portion of state from an API call, as this page is not the main page of my app.

The problem now is when a user navigates to a student details page say:

`/student/5`

And then refreshes the page since they are on a different component and the   `componentDidMount()` of the `StudentsView.js` component is no longer called, I end up with a empty students array in my state, so in my students detail component student will be undefined:

```
function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  const studentId = +ownProps.params.id
  let student = { id: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' }
  if (studentId && state.students.length > 0) {
    student = getStudentById(state.students, studentId)
  }
  return {
    student: student
  }
}
```

Is there a way of working around this aside from ensuring that the `loadStudensts()` action is called in the initial app load?

What is the best practise, do I navigate the user back to the listings page if the list of `students` is empty? Is there a way, and is it recommend for me to disatch the `loadStudents()` action inside the `StudentDetailView.js` component?

Basically, how do I make sure students portion of state is always populated when the user is on the `StudentDetailView.js`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using redux, so in your StudentDetail component you can dispatch an action say `loadStudentById(5)` and in your action you can check if the data returned by `loadStudents` in available if not you can you can first `loadStudents` followed by `loadStudent()`.

```
//somewhere in your actions
function loadStudent(studentId) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(loadStudents()).then(() => {
      const students = getState().students.get('students')
      const student = students.find(s => s.id === studentId)

      // This action will set the student in reducer when type is matched
      dispatch(setStudent(student))
    })
  }
}
```

so `setStudent` could be something like

```
function setStudent(student) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_STUDENT',
    payload: student
  }
}
```

To check if student are already available and to avoid API call in your loadStudents you can do something like that

```
function loadStudents() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const students = getState().students.get('students')

    // Return early avoiding API call
    if (students && students.length > 0) {
      return Promise.resolve()
    }

    // actual API loading logic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this now after some thought is to dispatch a `loadStudentById()` action on the student detail component. I could do this inside `componentDidMount()`:

```
  componentDidMount () {
    const studentId = this.props.params.id
    this.props.actions.loadStudentById(studentId)
  }
```

Turns out [the seed project I'm using](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) has a unique approach to loading routes asynchronously, and they advise against using life cycle hooks to dispacth actions to retrieve data. Basically loading the component only after a route matches, at which point I can intercept this hook and dispatch a `getStudentById()` action before the component is loaded. Something like:

```
import { loadStudentById } from '../../actions/studentActions'

export default (store) => ({
  path : 'student/:id',
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const studentId = nextState.params.id
      store.dispatch(loadStudentById(studentId))
      const student = require('./components/StudentDetailView').default
      cb(null, student)
    }, 'student')
  }
})
```

More details here:

[Populating a Component On Load](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/issues/800)

A very sleek approach by the creators of this project.